# Return to language specific variable in the -body parameter from (Send-MailMessage)

Tags: powershell, return-type

I have defined several variables with different Body Content that I can refence later in Send-MailMessage command with the -Body Parameter.

```
$bodyit = @"
Hello Italy
"@

$bodyde = @"
Hello Germany
"@

$bodymx = @"
Hello Mexico
"@

$bodye = @"
Hello International
"@

if ($var -eq "IT"){
return $bodyit
}elseif ($var -eq "DE"){
return $bodyde
}elseif ($var -eq "MX"){
return $bodymx
}else {return $bodye}

Send-MailMessage -from "..." -to "..." -subject "..." -smtp "..." -Body $return to specific $body
```

How can I achieve that I get the correct return type in the Send-MailMessage?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are returning a value, but not actually storing it anywhere. Use a 3rd variable to store the value. Like - `if ($var -eq "IT"){
$ThirdVariable = $bodyit` and so on... Use `$ThirdVariable ` as value to the `-body` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I don't thought about a $ThirdVariable. This is the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a switch instead of multiple if, also store the value you actually want into `$body` and use `$body` in the `Send-Mail` for the correct response.

Try it like this:

```
switch ($var)
{
  IT {
    $body = @"
    Hello Italy
    "@
  }
  DE {
    $body = @"
    Hello Germany
    "@
  }
  MX {
    $body = @"
    Hello Mexico
    "@
  }
  default {
    $body = @"
    Hello International
    "@
  }
}

Send-MailMessage -from "..." -to "..." -subject "..." -smtp "..." -Body $body
```

Comment: And where is here the 3rd variable?

Comment: @Hakikat41 You don't need a 3rd variable, since you don't store each response in a seperate variable, instead you directly assign the correct response to the `$body` variable.

Comment: The `"@` will all have to be in the first position to avoid errors and the indent will be part of the text. If formatted ccordingly it doesn't look as pretty.

Comment: @LotPings, No @" text "@ is the correct way and doesn't produces any errors.

Comment: Evrey doc you find will tell you this `There are some specific rules for where those starting and ending marks appear. You have to type it just as follows: The @" must be the last thing on the first line, then you type whatever arguments you want passed, and finally the closing "@ must be the first two characters on the next line` not following that rule will cause an error

Comment: Yes, now you are a bit clearer and  I am in your same opinion, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow your approach compounding the variable name from `body` and `$var` using the cmdlet `Get-Variable`

```
If ($var -in 'it','de','mx'){
    $Body = (get-variable -name "body$var").Value
} else {
    $Body = $bodye
}
```